# File not found Exception thrown, even when given right path

Tags: file, filenotfoundexception

This is the code, program throws file not found exception at collection.addFromFile(f), even when I give it a valid pathway.

```
if(choice == 4) {
    System.out.println("Enter title: ");
    String toImport = scan.nextLine();
    File f = new File(toImport);
   collection.addFromFile(f);
}
```